# Generic method that returns String in java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to use a generic method to return a String value

This is the method call

```
System.out.printf("%s", impresionTabulada(arregloEntrada[i]),i);
```

This is the method

```
public static <E> String impresionTabulada(E elemento, int indx){
    if(indx%4==0)
        return String.format("%s\n", elemento);
    else
        return String.format("%s\t\t", elemento);
}
```

but the compiler throws this error

> "Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type The method
>   impresionTabulada(E, int) in the type
>   EJERC18_6_PruebaMetodoGenerico_ImpresionTabulada is not applicable for
>   the arguments
>   (E)   EJERC18_6_PruebaMetodoGenerico_ImpresionTabulada.java   /1 libro de
>   java D&D/CAP18/com/ejercDietel/Ejercicios line 23 Java Problem"

I have been researching about this issue but i dont know what i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should be `System.out.printf("%s", impresionTabulada(arregloEntrada[i],i));`. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Simplified Signature of `impresionTabulada`

```
String impresionTabulada(E, int)
```

It takes in 2 parameters, the first of type `E`, and the second of type `int`.

### Substitution of `impresionTabulada`

```
// This is NOT code...this is just a substitution for later!
x = impresionTabulada(arregloEntrada[i]) // Take note that is only taking in 1 parameter - arregloEntrada[i]
```

### Therefore...

Your `printf` expression is this...

```
System.out.printf("%s", x, i);                                     // This `x` is from above
System.out.printf("%s", x                                   , i);  // This `x` is from above - expanded
System.out.printf("%s", impresionTabulada(arregloEntrada[i]), i);  // This is your bad code!
```

As you can see, it is your `printf(...)` function that is taking the argument that you want as the second `impresionTabulada(...)` argument.

### Solution

```
System.out.printf("%s", impresionTabulada(arregloEntrada[i], i) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the method with a single argument `impresionTabulada(arregloEntrada[i])` but you defined it with two parameters.

I'm assuming the method call should be :

```
System.out.printf("%s", impresionTabulada(arregloEntrada[i],i));
```

Comment: It is Solved, thank you I didnt see that